# Run my python script from Command line give empty dataframe

Tags: python, powershell

if I run this script in Anaconda then I get result but when I use Powershell `python D:\script\RSSfeeds.py`  then the result is empty dataframe.

```py
import feedparser
import pandas as pd
rawrss = ['https://feeds.livep2000.nl?']
feeds = [] 
for url in rawrss:
    feeds.append(feedparser.parse(url))
posts = [] 
for feed in feeds:
    for post in feed.entries:
        posts.append((post.published, post.title, post.link, post.description, post.description.partition("(")[2].partition(")")[0].strip(), post.description.partition("(")[2].partition("0")[0].strip() , getattr(post, "geo_long",0), getattr(post, "geo_lat",0)))
df = pd.DataFrame(posts, columns = ['Date', 'Titel', 'link', 'summary', 'capcode', 'dienst', 'geo_long', 'geo_lat'] ) 
df['dienst'] = df['capcode'].str.replace(r'\d+', '').str.replace('-', '')
print(df)
```

what was my mistake. any suggestions?

Comment: I'm able to get the output with your code

Comment: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date, Titel, link, summary, capcode, dienst, geo_long, geo_lat]
Index: []

Comment: when you run this from command line Powershell like python D:\script\RSSfeeds.py then the output is empty dataframe

Comment: I found my problem